# Javascript open window with php variables in link?

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

what I need to do is open a new window to a link that has php variables in it. As far as I know, I cannot use php variables in javascript functions, so I tried this which does not seem to be working

```
$link="<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('http://www.fonefinder.net/findome.php?npa=$num1&nxx=$num2&thoublock=$num3&usaquerytype=Search+by+Number&cityname=
')</script>";
echo $link;
```

$num1, $num2, and $num3 are all php variables. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work because of line break...

Comment: What is the generated HTML/JavaScript (output) of your PHP script for this small piece of code? It is always important to provide this since there is a difference between what you "see" at the server side (the script) and what you have on the client side (the generated output).

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski What line break...

Comment: @CJSculti check agreco's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove linebreak:

```
$link="<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('http://www.fonefinder.net/findome.php?npa=$num1&nxx=$num2&thoublock=$num3&usaquerytype=Search+by+Number&cityname=')</script>";
echo $link;
```

Also, you should wrap the variables in braces: `${num1}`, otherwise they may be interpolated incorrectly.

Comment: No, it just does absolutley nothing, as it does not redirect, the way I have it now, with it echoing the script.

Comment: I'd also point out that this will break if the PHP variables include apostrophes or any of a number of other things - You need to first URL encode the parameters `urlencode()` and then escape them to be used inside a JS String (replace `'` and `\\` and probably some more). Of course, if you can _guarantee_ it will only ever be a number, this shouldn't be required

Answer (score 1):

```
$link="<script type='text/javascript'>window.open('http://www.fonefinder.net/findome.php?npa=".$num1."&nxx=".$num2."&thoublock=".$num3."&usaquerytype=Search+by+Number&cityname=')</script>";
echo $link;
```